# Jquery Animation not working a width specified as %

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm pretty new to javascript and javascript animate property in general please help me out. I would like the image to fill the entire body's width 50% --> 100% . I want it to change to 100% when i hover over it.

More words cause stackoverflow wants more

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="js/a.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/a.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="col-1" id="column1">
        <div class="col-1c" id="column1c">
            <img src="images/ngnl.jpg" onmouseover="colmover1()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.content{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
z-index:0;
position:relative;
}
.col-1{
position:relative;
float:left;
width:50%;
height:100%;
background-image:url('../images/ngnlfull.jpg'); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
.col-1c{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
float:left;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.col-1c img{
display:block;
margin:auto;
max-width:100%;
height:50%;
border-radius:50%;
margin-top:25%;
}
body{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px; 
outline: none;
border: 0px;
background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function colmover1(){
    var column1 = document.getElementById("column1");
    var column1c = document.getElementById("column1c");
    var column2 = document.getElementById("column2");
    var column2c = document.getElementById("column2c");

    column1.animate({width:'100%'});
}
```

Comment: colmover1 is nerver attached. An animation requires, from and to and duration at least. Read the doc. Make sure to propagate width and height when using multiple containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// used css
```

```css
.content{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
z-index:0;
position:relative;
}
.col-1{
position:relative;
float:left;
  width:50%;
  transition: width 0.5s;
height:100%;
background-image:url('../images/ngnlfull.jpg'); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

.col-1:hover{
width:100%;
}
.col-1c{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
float:left;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.col-1c img{
display:block;
margin:auto;
width:100%;
border-radius:50%;
margin-top:25%;
}
body{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px; 
outline: none;
border: 0px;
background-image: url('../images/bg.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="js/a.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/a.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="col-1" id="column1">
        <div class="col-1c" id="column1c">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcdbj.jpg?s=48&g=1" onmouseover="colmover1()">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```